# Best way to wait for another action in flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm using react and flux (facebook implementation). In my component I should do something like:

```
componentDidMount () {
  UserActions.loadUser(this.props.username);
  PublicationActions.findByUser(this.state.userId);
  UserStore.on('CHANGE', this._setUser);
  // ...
},
```

The problem is `this.state.userId` will be defined only when request triggered by `UserActions.loadUser` is finished.

So the only way of resolving this problem is putting something like:

```
if (this.state.userId && !this.state.publications) {
  PublicationActions.findByUser(this.state.userId);
}
```

directly to `render()` method. I don't like this solution cause `render()` is for rendering and I don't want to mess any business logic in it.

The only acceptable solution I have found is have special component hierarchy for this case like:

```
<User username={someVar}>
  <PublicationsList userId={this.state.userId}/>
</User>
```

This will enforce `PublicationsList` to be smart component (with state and so) but I'd like it to be dumb renderer. Is this the only way or there's something better?

Comment: Have you considered having your component listen for the user store and calling the `findByUser` action when it updates?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need store which is listening  on `UserAction.loadUser` finish.
2. You invoke this action.
3. In your component you register callback which listening your new store.
4. When your store invoke your callback, then you have in this callback function access to userId from this store. (Im not sure but maybe your UserStore do wiat I write).
5. In this callback function you invoke

`PublicationActions.findByUser(YourStore.getState().userId)`

6. In render function you check if you have userId. If no then show some loading info. If tez then show normal rending data.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I don't like the approach cause (if I got it right) this will lead to continuous repeating of `Publication.findBuUser()` request when  UserStore emits change event (can do it frequently). I can check of course if there's publications in state before doing it but it seems to me like redundant `if` statement. This checking can be tricky as well if there's conflict between more than two stores. I'll accept your answer as correct If nobody posts here anything better. Let me know if I misunderstand something

Comment: You invoke findByUser in store callback. And this callback is invoked by store after loadUser finished, And only then. Your stores should  emit callbacks only after certain action finished. If your store emit callback only when loadUser finished then this callback will be invoked once. And therefore findByUser will be invoked once.

Answer (score 1):

You could expand your `loadUser` method to accept callback with payload as arguments.

ie:

```
loadUser(username, callback) {
  // some ajax stuff
  callback(payload);
}
```

Then, in your jsx file you could write something like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
  UserActions.loadUser(this.props.username, (user) => {
    PublicationActions.findByUser(user.userId);
  });
  UserStore.on('CHANGE', this._setUser);
  // ...
},
```